# Swift and Android - Can I exclude binaries from certain target deployments?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, android-productflavors

I have an Android and iOS app that can be whitelabeled to several different clients,
This could grow, so I don't want to manage 4 different projects and keep it as singular a codebase as much as possible.

One issue i have, is each client has a different third party provider for Feature X (say, working with a smart-light system).

I am looking into feature toggles, so that I can have a config file that specifies which services should be passed around and what features are activated for each client - but the problem is some of these third party binaries cause things to "happen" even if I don't instantiate a class using them specifically, like registering certain things in the background or requiring permissions from the user etc just because I have the binary included.

Is there a way to programatically ignore binaries for certain deployments of my app?

I am trying to copy the Android 'flavors' system, and I haven't found a solution there either but for now iOS is the priority.

Interested if there's a solution for either system or how others have approached this situation.

Comment: For android, flavors are a good way to achieve this. Dynamic feature delivery is also a possibility.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderHoffmann thanks for the response, but have you got any examples or further reading on how to actually exclude or include certain gradle packages / swift pods based on configuration?

Comment: Is this a Swift Android app?

Answer (score 1):

## Using flavors

Gradle allows you to include dependencies only for certain flavors. You can just write the flavor name in front of your import statement (usually it's `implementation` and `api`).

For example, if you have the flavor `demo`, you can include a certain dependency by importing it with `demoImplementation`:

```
android {
...
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension "version"
        }
        full {
            dimension "version"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // This will only be included when you build the "demo" flavor
    demoImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
}
```

## Using dynamic feature module

Dynamic feature modules are modules which can be downloaded dynamically after an application has been installed or at install time.
For example, if some feature requires NFC, you can extract this code to a dynamic feature module and let android install it only on devices, which have NFC. Devices without NFC won't even download it.

Or you download and install a feature which is not used by most users only after a user presses a button in the app.

An example for this can be found in the [On Demand Modules codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery/index.html#0).

Comment: Hi - I somehow missed this answer...how does this work for the code that would call the module? I.e. if I remove the dependencies and hide the module that references that dependency, how would my build work considering my code would likely have a reference to that module? Would I have to programatically comment out code or am I missing something? Thanks !